# How to run AWS CLI Command Through Robot Framework?

Tags: amazon-s3, robotframework, aws-cli

Updating my question : My test scenario is to get the file sizes in a particular S3 bucket. For this I have installed robotframework-aws library. Now I am not sure which keyword to use in order to get the file sizes. Here is the code i have written till now :

```
Run AWS CLI Command to capture file size of S3 MRL Hub Source
Create Session With Keys    region: us-east-1    access_key: xxxx   secret_key: xxxx    aws_session_token: str
Read File From S3    bucket_name: com-abc-def-ghi    key: name/of/the/file/i/am/looking/for.parquet
```

With this code i am getting the following error :

```
InvalidRegionError: Provided region_name 'region: us-east-1' doesn't match a supported format.
```

Comment: What have you tired so far? Is there a Python API for AWS?

Comment: Hi Bence, i did find an AWSLibrary for robot framework.i have downloaded it. but i am unable to import.it throws me 'Unknown library' erro even though i have added it to my red.xml file. CTRL+1 did not help.

Comment: I see, please edit your question and add how you have tired to use AWSLibrary.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Run](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html#Run) command, which is part of the `OperatingSystem` Library and it is already included by default when you install RobotFramework.

With this you can make Robotframework run any command prompt that you which. For example:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  OperatingSystem

*** Test Cases ***
Test run command
    ${output}=  Run  aws --version
    log  ${output}
```

The problem comes when you want to use the interactive capabilities of `aws configure`. I mean, you can't expect that Robotframework test case asks for your input. In this case you need to provide all `aws configure` [options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-options.html) before hand. This means that you need to prepare a `profile` file for your test case and then you can concatenate more commands, like:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test run command
    ${output}=  Run  aws configure --profile <profilename> && set https_proxy http://webproxy.xyz.com:8080
    log  ${output}
```

Or better use a `profile` file directly with s3, like, `aws s3 ls --profile <profilename>`.

Bear in mind that the best way to do this is using some kind of external library, like `AWSLibrary` or create your own [custom library](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-test-libraries) using [boto3 Python library](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html).

Comment: Hi, my first approach will be through aws library. i have updated the question accrodingly. can you suggest anything on this?

Comment: @Mekhla please be aware of the proper way to pass options to the keyword, you should not use named parameters, i.e `region: us-east-1` (you should not use colon either), instead, you need to use **positional arguments** as mentioned in this [example](https://github.com/teaglebuilt/robotframework-aws/blob/master/tests/robot/testsuites/S3Tests/DownloadFile.robot). Once you download the file you can check for the size of the file